# Extend SQL Query Timeout in Azure Logic Apps

Tags: sql, azure-logic-apps

I am running a logic app that triggers multiple SQL queries. When these queries have ran for 10 minutes and not completed the query, they timeout. Is there any way to extend this timeout length?

Comment: You mean SQL or the logic app times out?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to extend this timeout length

- If you require extended timeout for logic apps then as per this [Microsoft document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-limits-and-config?tabs=azure-portal#http-request-limits) Either it may be Inbound or Outbound requests it has been defined as 120 sec. if you are running operations/queries for longer try using [asynchronous calling](https://github.com/logicappsio/LogicAppsAsyncResponseSample).

[image]

- For increasing SQL query timeout we have an option of using Azure Elastic Job agent as per this Microsoft Document.

[image]

- You can even try using Azure functions where you can run queries longer time without interruption and if you still want to use logic apps you can call functions from logic apps using HTTP trigger.
- Here are a few related links about [Azure functions](https://serversncode.com/azure-functions-with-sql/) and SQL stored procedures and calling azure function in [logic apps.](https://medium.com/@jeffhollan/calling-long-running-functions-from-logic-apps-6d7ba5044701)